# Implied probability to avoid direct calculation in a game question

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

In a problem with the following general set up:

2 or more people are playing a game whose outcome is determined by chance. For the purposes of clarifying the question, i'll give a more specific example, but I'm asking this in a more general sense. In this example, 2 people are throwing dice and the person who wins is the first person who shoots dice that add up to 6. I realize that the person who goes first has a different probability of winning than the person who goes second, and I know how to  figure it out, that is by using geometric progressions. Here is my question:

IF one is answering a question such as this, and if the problem happens to have a component that requires one to know the probability that the second player wins, in order to save time, can I assume that the probability that the second play wins is 1-(Probability that the first player wins)? Is this extendable to 3,4...n players?

Answer (score 1):

Let $W_i$ denote the event that player $i$ wins. Assuming there are no draws in the game, the possible outcomes are $\{ W_i \vert i \in \{1,2,...,n\}\}$. By Law of Total Probability, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n P(W_i) = 1$. So, for $n=2$, you have $P(W_2) = 1- P(W_1)$ and you can get away with just finding $P(W_1)$.

For general $n$, you only get $$P(W_i) = 1 - \sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\neq i}}^n P(W_j).$$ So, you'll need to know every other probability to get away with not computing one. Long story short, for $n$ players, you'll need to compute $n-1$ probabilities.